# Does chicken manure interfere with fruit trees?

Tags: fruit-trees, plant-health, fertilizer, nitrogen

I have a lemon and orange tree which chickens roost in and poo around and causing the trees not to bear much fruit.

What can I do to eliminate the nitrogen in the soil? I cannot move the chickens because I don't have enough room.

Comment: Could you please explain why you think it is the chickens that cause the tree to bear so little fruit?